# How to resize a line, defined by two points, so that its constrained by a maximum line length in C++

Tags: c++, geometry, line

I am having some difficulties working out how I can constrain a line to a maximum length. Let's say I have two SDL_Point's `p1` and `p2` which construct a line, `p2` is determined by the mouse position and `p1` is constant. I have a function that calculates the length of the line and I check if that length is greater than the maximum length. If it is greater than the maximum length I want to scale the line so that the angle is the same and the effect will be that `p2` is scaled to meet the maximum length criteria.

I am using this method to calculate the distance:

```
double Foo::CalculateDistance(SDL_Point p1, SDL_Point p2)
{
    int xd = p2.x- p1.x;
    int yd = p2.y - p1.y;
    return sqrt(xd*xd + yd*yd);
}

SDL_Point Foo::CalculatePosition(int mousePosX, int mousePosY)
{
    SDL_Point p2;
    p2.x = mousePosX;
    p2.y = mousePosY;
    lineLength = (int) CalculateDistance(p2,p1);
    if (lineLength > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
    {
        // Buggy code 
        p2.x /= lineLength;
        p2.y /= lineLength;
    }

    return p2;
}
```

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: find the *angle*, and then `p2.x` and `p2.y` can be calculated through `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: @Jongware that's the hard way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a 2d vector class. That will make things much simpler.
And then use it like

```
p2 = p1 + (p2 - p1).normalized() * MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
```

or without vectors

```
p2.x = p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / lineLength * MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
p2.y = p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / lineLength * MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
```

and a complete example

```
SDL_Point p2;
p2.x = mousePosX;
p2.y = mousePosY;

lineLength = (int) CalculateDistance(p2,p1);

if (lineLength > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
{
    p2.x = p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / lineLength * MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
    p2.y = p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / lineLength * MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
}

return p2;
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am not allowed to in this project great suggestion for some one viewing this in the future though!

Comment: You forgot the conclusion: `p2.x = p1.x + x; p2.y = p1.y + y;`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys appreciate it!